# Air Conditioner question

Tags: central-air

Is it typical for 1 of the (pipe) lines from my outdoor AC unit to have condensation? The AC tech added 1Ib of freon yesterday. Don't know if this has anything to do with the condensation.

Comment: Yes, there is generally a condensate line coming from the evaporator (i.e. the COLD AIR side) section of the unit.  The cold not only cools your air but the drop in temperature causes moisture in the air to condense out.  It has to go somewhere and there is usually a drain line.

Comment: Norah, do you mean that there is condensation ( moisture ) on the outside of one the pipes ?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for the suction line /vapor line ( going to the outside compressor) to have condensation. The amount depends on humidity and the characteristics of your unit. If you get frost on it , have someone check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If it's warm weather the small should be warm.

The large should have condensation.  Beer can cold is the old rule of thumb for how it should feel.